# Type ahead search for type instead of method name

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

If you start typing in Xcode something like `[self`<kbd>Space</kbd> you see something like this:

[image: Xcode autocompletion]

What I want now is instead of filtering the results by method names I want to type e.g. `NSString` and get all methods back that return `NSString` (like description in this example) or all properties that I can set with `NSString`.